# How to add and activate react theme developed by npx-create-wptheme in wpengine

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wp-enqueue-scripts, wpengine

I have developed react theme for wordpress using npx-create-wptheme template it is running in localhost (xampp and wordpress) If I place react theme inside /wp-content/themes folder.

I have created sftp user on wpengine and I have placed the react app inside wp-content/themes folder but it is showing only blank white screen in wpengine

**Error**

```
wpThemeClient.js:46 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8090/' failed: 
start @ wpThemeClient.js:46
0.chunk.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.chunk.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
bundle.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.chunk.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
wpThemeClient.js:128 It's possible the browser refresh server has disconnected.
You can manually refresh the page if necessary.
main.chunk.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I have tried with build folder and without build folder also